# Обработка композитного сигнала

Tags: c++, arduino, обработка-сигналов, vga

Осуществима ли данная вещь: на входе у меня композитный видеосигнал. Мне необходимо из него сделать аналоговый сигнал для VGA порта. VGA работает с RGB. А также судя по распиновке, я не узнавал, там есть вертикальная и горизонтальная синхронизации. Все это дело, если осуществимо, будет работать на Arduino UNO.

Собственно в чем моя неуверенность. Возможно ли по методу преобразования Фурье вытащить из композита RGB? Как идет представление сигнала на программном уровне, чтобы взять сигнал обработать и отправить дальше? Хватит ли мощности uno для обработки хотя бы статической картинки, позже если удастся, буду делать прототип на Atmel?

И еще такая вещь. Существует региональная зависимость. PAL и NTSC/NTSC-J форматы. 50 и 60 герцовые. В чем их различие, кроме как скорости частоты кадров в секунду?

Интересует очень сильно литература которая может помочь мне "исследовать" данную область.

Comment: 13 долларов стоит конвертер RCA-VGA. А почитать про это нашёл следующее http://www.ece.tamu.edu/~reddy/ee449/labs/lab5.pdf

Comment: для этого есть мастеркард а свой велосипед бесценен. заинтересовался мк и есть потребность и желание сотворить такой вот конвертер с пасьянсом пауком и прочим.

Comment: 640x480x60 = 18.432 МГц.